# Use Clojure interfaces in a Java library project

Tags: java, interface, clojure, dependencies

I would like to use some of the Clojure interfaces in a Java library project in several situations where it would be useful for my Java classes to implement them. In particular:

- [clojure.lang.ISeq](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ISeq.java)
- [clojure.lang.IFn](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java)

Doing this would make my Java library much more user-friendly for Clojure-based users.

However I don't want to import the whole of `clojure.jar` as a dependency - since it is relatively large and my library is mainly targeted at Java users.

Is there a way to import and develop against the Clojure interfaces without bringing in the rest of Clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

1. unpack the clojure jar
2. put only the .class you need into a directory named LightweightClojure
3. run you test appli (test + lib + LightweightClojure)
4. goto 2 until it works
5. zip the LightweightClojure directory into LightweightClojure.jar

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven, you can us [Maven Shade Plugin's minimize-jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) configuration.